# Why is 1 dimension the highest possible of the vector space of a total antisymmetric tensor

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors

$\alpha_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ are 2 totally antisymmetric tensors. With $\epsilon_{0123} = 1$ we can write: $\alpha \mathbb{1} = \alpha \epsilon_{0123} \rightarrow \alpha_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}= \alpha\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ and thus, the space of total antisymmetric tensors has 1 dimension.

Given this proof, how is one able to make the claim that the space has only 1 dimension. From $\alpha_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}= \alpha\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, I can't see why this statement should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've shown that two vectors in that space are always linearly dependent. Any nonzero totally antisymmetric tensor $\alpha_{ijkl}$ in that space constitutes a basis, since every other tensor is a scalar multiple of $\alpha_{ijkl}$.